# Angular template driven custom validator

Tags: angular, angular6

sorry for my English, i am working on angular 6 application and i am adding custom validator which checks on database file exists or not but i want to call that validator on input blur only, can any  please help?

This my sample html code:

```
 <mat-form-field class="ais_form_field_tbox" >
                        <input class="ais_tbox" matInput name="fileType" #fileType="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="fileTypeCreation.fileType" appFileTypeExists [(allFileTypes)]="filetypelist">
                    </mat-form-field>
                  <mat-error>
                    <div *ngIf="!fileType.valid && fileType.touched">
                      FileType is required!
                    </div>
                   <div *ngIf="fileType.errors?.fileExists && (fileType.touched || fileType.dirty)" class="cross-validation-error-message alert alert-danger">
                      File Already Exists.
                    </div>
                  </mat-error>
```

This is my directive which i have create and declared using:

```
@Directive({
     selector: '[appFileTypeExists][ngModel]',
      providers: [
          { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: FileTypeExistsDirective, 
          multi: true }
      ]
     })
      export class FileTypeExistsDirective implements  Validators {
        @Input() allFileTypes: any;
        constructor() {}

       validate(c: AbstractControl): { fileExists: boolean } {
      if (this.allFileTypes.findIndex(x => x.fileType === c.value)){
        c.setErrors({fileExists: true});
       } else {
         return null;
       }
      }

    }
```

my problem is that my directive validate function is getting called on dialog box only but want it to fired on input blur event what changes i have to do.
yes i have form in dialog box.

Comment: You shouldnt mutate the abstract control given to validate in your validator directive. Instead, return the error object.

Comment: For the blur condition, you could simply check inside of the validation if the control was touched or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your approach to validating the input field, I will share the approach I used that validates on field blur.

I ended up using FormControl via reactive forms to attach my custom validator to the field.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

html

```
<form name="testFormGroup ">    
    <input formControlName="testCustomValidator">

    <div *ngIf="testFormGroup.get('testCustomValidator').hasError('errorInMath')">
    1 + 1 does not equal 3. </div>
 </form>
```

component

```
var testFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  testCustomValidator: new FormControl('', {validators: [Validators.required, 
  this.testCustomValidator.bind(this)]
  })
})
```

custom validator

```
testCustomValidator(AC: AbstractControl){
  if (1+1!=3){
    return {errorInMath: true};
  }else{
    return null;
   }
  }
```

**Please Note:** using ngModel with reactive forms will be deprecated, if you choose to explore this solution you will need to use the formGroup to set your field default value and use testFormGroup['testCustomValidator'].Value to pass the field values to your component.

Comment: ,thank you, but you know we developers sometime have to stick with old ways, but i got solution in directive instead of c.setErrors({fileExists: true}); this line i just have to return {fileExists: true} and have to check c.touched in if condition :)